# Python Move Files from AWS S3 to SMB Share

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, smb

I am currently trying to write Python code to Transfer files between an AWS S3 Bucket and AWS FSx Windows SMB share.  This will be used in a Lambda function.

I can achieve this by using the Lambda temporary storage /tmp and transferring the files from S3 to /tmp and then from /tmp to the SMB share, but it would be more efficient to transfer the files directly from S3 to the SMB share.
I can open the file directly from the S3 bucket with the following code using the Python AWS BOTO3 SDK:

```
fileobj = s3client.get_object(
    Bucket=bucketname,
    Key = file_to_read)
```

I am then attempting  to write the contents of the S3 file to the SMB share with the following code using the Python SMBConnection class from the  pysmb package:

```
connection.storeFile(service_name='s3-test', 
                     path='test-write.txt',
                     file_obj = fileobj["Body"])
```

The test-write.txt file is successfully created on the SMB share, but it is empty with 0 size.  There are no errors and the program completes successfully.
I think this must be something to do with the python “file like object” that the file_obj is expecting.  As there is no error I assume the fileobj["Body"]) I am using is correct?

Any ideas would be very welcome?

Comment: Any luck on your script?  I would like to do something very similar so interested in how this turned out for you

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be from the wrong pointer position the method try to write.

The position of the file pointer can be changed using the seek method of file object.

Put `seek(0)` line before writing like this.

```
file_obj.seek(0)
connection.storeFile(...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion., but the boto3 get_object does not expose the seek method.